# Ordering rows by count in a separate pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a main table: Images and votes.

The votes contains 2 fields: Id, image_id

What I wish to do is query the images table and return them ordered by the amount of votes in the vote table.

Currently:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
    'SELECT *
    FROM images
    LIMIT 10'
);
```

I understand basic left joins, but cannot think how to order them by count of votes. Just need a starting example.

Thanks

Comment: which field contains the votes entered? or does each line in the column table represents one vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each row in your VOTES table means one vote towards the image, this should work: **[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cf72/7)**

```
SELECT *, COUNT(v.image_id)
FROM images AS i
LEFT JOIN votes AS v ON i.id=v.image_id 
GROUP BY i.id
ORDER BY v.image_id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1 (id int);
insert into t1 values (1), (2), (3);
drop table if exists t2;
create table t2 (id int, img_id int);
insert into t2 values (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4,1), (5,3), (6,2);

select * 
  from t1 
    left join 
      (select img_id, count(*) count 
           from t2 
         group by img_id) c 
    on img_id=t1.id 
  order by count
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9db09/1)